# Store result from SQL in array for JSON delivery in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

This is my definition to handle result from MySQL. I need to put records from my request into data defined as array (data => array()). How do I put all my records from MySQL into my array?

```
$mydata = array('dataset_data' =>
(array('limit' => null,
 'transform' => null,
 'column_index' => null,
 'column_names' => array ('Name1','Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name6', 'Name6', 'Age','Birthday'),
 'start_date' => '2006-08-28',
 'end_date' => '2018-08-24',
 'frequency' => 'daily',
 'data' => array()
)));
```

Comment: What are you using to get the results from the database (PDO, MYSQLI)? Can you provide the code for that?

Comment: `$mydata['dataset_data']['data'] = $myMySQLData`

Comment: Just MYSQLI. It's just a simple Select from where id= xx. I can store it like $data = array($row['Name1'], $row['Name2'], $row['Name3'], $row['Name4'], $row['Name5], $row['Name6'], $row['Age'] , $row['Birthday']); It just doesn't work for me when I try to store it in $mydata[dataset_data][data]. I only see the last record from my sql result.